# Css option width error

Tags: css

Im having this problem.

css:

```
select {width:500px;}
option {width: 500px;}
```

[image]

The problem is always there is a white extre space in option(please see the image).

How can I fix this, pls help me out.

Comment: Why are you giving `option` a width anyway?

Comment: @putvande If I dont add width for option, option's width will be equals to it's content and break my style
deekey: chrome/firefox has the same view

Comment: If you only set a `width` on `select` it won't break any style. Your option might be wider but it won't break anything. Also, setting a style for `option` is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: The `option` tag is very limited in terms of styling, perhaps mimicking a dropdown will give you more customization :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you not add CSS rule for `option`, just use `select{ width: 500px; }`

Comment: If I dont add width for option, option's width will be equals to it's content and break my style

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9JmQx/)**

**css**

```
select, option {
    width:500px;  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;

}
```